# I am unable to change language to English using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have tried all the following possibilities but none of them are working for English language. Although they are working for other languages such as French and Spanish etc, but not for English( US & GB)

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.addArguments("lang=en-GB");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
 driver.get(TestData.baseUrl);
```

Also this one,

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String chrome_locale = "en-usu";
    prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", chrome_locale);
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: `en-usu` should be `en-us`

Comment: @cruisepandey tried that. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

While executing, the below code, make sure that this line `langs.put("language symbol here (originally)", "en");` the first args should be the language the website loads.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("start-maximized");
option.addArguments("test-type");
 
option.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
option.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", true);


Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> langs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
langs.put("language symbol here (originally)", "en");
prefs.put("translate", "{'enabled' : true}");
prefs.put("translate_whitelists", langs);
option.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

driver.get("Your url");
```

Comment: Can you send a link where I can see the language codes for all languages?  I want to see estonian language code

Comment: It worked. But how can I make it generic? I don't when running in the pipeline, what is going to be the original language?

Comment: @SammarAhmad : W3 schools had documented it better, see here all the codes https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: also to make it generic, it's difficult to know the language, cause devs do not put `html[@lang]` xpath or meta attribute, but do check in your case, if it is present then you can extract that info using Selenium, so you have to look under HTML DOM to see if there's any lang attribute